# RoR/Refile Gem - Images not loading in Microsoft Edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, microsoft-edge, refile

We are using the refile gem to display the images in our platform, they do work well on different browsers except for Microsoft Edge. Is there a different format or limitation for Microsoft Edge that I should know about it?

(I don't have Microsoft Edge, so can't test it directly)

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: id recommend using https://www.browserstack.com to check it and you will see the errors first hand. You can do a free trial.

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team. We provide free virtual machines for testing purposes. You can find them over at [http://edge.ms](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). The images are [appearing for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kjQfD.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked with MS Edge 25.10586.0.0 / EdgeHTML 13.10586 and images have not been displayed.

I suppose this happens because images are sent as application/octet-stream and Edge doesn't have enough informations to display them (need to be confirmed).

But on [refile github page](https://github.com/refile/refile#additional-metadata) you could see it's possible to add metadata for each file loaded like:

```
class StoreMetadata < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :profile_image_filename, :string
    add_column :users, :profile_image_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :profile_image_content_type, :string
  end
end
```

These fields will be filled automatically after a file load and fixes the issue on my refile example app.

**Disclaimer: Be carefull with the following actions, please make some tests before doing this on a production environment**

It's possible to add missing informations to your existing files.

Currently `Refile` seems to only use filename extension to extract the content-type. Therefore we need to extract the content-type with file content and create a filename with the corresponding extension for each uploaded file.

There is probably many ways to do that. I'll describe a method I used on my refile application.

Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :profile_image
end
```

First run the previous migration to add missing fields.

In the gemfile add the gem `mimemagic` and run `bundel install`. This one can determine content-type of a file by the content.

Then for each `User` extract profile_image's content-type and add a correct filename.

```
User.all.each do |u|
  subtype = MimeMagic.by_magic(u.profile_image.read).subtype
  u.profile_image_filename = "profile_image.#{subtype}" if u.profile_image_filename.nil?
  u.save
 end
```

And that's all.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time. I'll start looking in this direction. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Hey @YannVery is there an easy way to add the information on the existing files?